# Compare the previous value of a cell with the current one

Tags: excel, vba, record

Each of the cells in the “O2: O20” range is populated with numerical values. Next to each one of these cells there is a cell that is also populated with numerical values ​​depending on the value that exists in "O2: 020". For example: If "O2" = 10.2 then the cell on its side "P2" = 1000 but then "P2" = 500, then "P2" = 600, then "P2" = 50; in short, "P2" can take any positive Natural value. I would like to calculate the difference between the previous value that "P2" takes and the current value that it can take as long as "O2" remains with the same value. If the value of "O2" changes, then the difference is not important to me: For example: if "O2" = 10.2 and "P2" = 50 and then "O2" = 10 and "P2" = 3000, in this case, no I want to know the difference, because "O2" is not the same for both cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I could understand your problem. Please see this solution.
It is using Option Base 1.
Updated program for writing the difference into the Q column.
If the message is not needed please delete or Rem the line of the last MsgBox.

```
Option Base 1
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Static declaration to safe the previous values and change status
    Static vO As Variant
    Static vP As Variant
    Static bolOChanged() As Boolean
    
    'Set up the ranges
    Dim rngO As Range, rngP As Range, rngQ As Range
    Set rngO = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("O2:O20")
    Set rngP = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("P2:P20")
    Set rngQ = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("Q2:Q20") 'Range for results
    
    'If the change is not in the range then ignore
    If Intersect(Union(rngO, rngP), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    'Prevent unhandelt multiply changes. If multiply changes required than the
    'Target range shall be loop through
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        rngO.Value = vO
        rngP.Value = vP
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        MsgBox "You cannot change more the one cell in the range of: " & Union(rngO, rngP).Address
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'At the firs occasion the current status has to be saved
    If VarType(vO) < vbArray Then
        vO = rngO.Value
        vP = rngP.Value
        ReDim bolOChanged(1 To UBound(vO))
    End If
    
    Dim iIndex As Long 'Adjust the index of the array to the Row of Target cell
    iIndex = Target.Row - rngO(1).Row + 1
    
    If Not Intersect(rngO, Target) Is Nothing Then
        'Change was in O range, so next P change shall be ignored
        bolOChanged(iIndex) = True
    Else
        'rngP changed
        If bolOChanged(iIndex) Then
            'There was a previous O range change, ignore
            bolOChanged(iIndex) = False 'Delete the recent change flag
            vP(iIndex, 1) = Target.Value 'Store the value
        Else
            rngQ(iIndex).Value = Target.Value - vP(iIndex, 1)
            MsgBox "Value change from: " & vP(iIndex, 1) & ", to: " & Target.Value & ". Difference is: " & Target.Value - vP(iIndex, 1)
            vP(iIndex, 1) = Target.Value 'Store the value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

UPDATE: This version is working with multiply entries.

```
Option Base 1
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Static declaration to safe the previous values and change status
    Static vO As Variant
    Static vP As Variant
    Static bolOChanged() As Boolean
    
    'Set up the ranges
    Dim rngO As Range, rngP As Range, rngQ As Range
    Set rngO = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("O2:O20")
    Set rngP = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("P2:P20")
    Set rngQ = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("Q2:Q20") 'Range for results
    
    'If the change is not in the range then ignore
    If Intersect(Union(rngO, rngP), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        
    'At the firs occasion the current status has to be saved
    If VarType(vO) < vbArray Then
        vO = rngO.Value
        vP = rngP.Value
        ReDim bolOChanged(1 To UBound(vO))
    End If
    
    Dim iIndex As Long 'Adjust the index of the array to the Row of Target cell
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In Target
        iIndex = item.Row - rngO(1).Row + 1
        If Not Intersect(rngO, item) Is Nothing Then
            'Change was in O range, so next P change shall be ignored
            bolOChanged(iIndex) = True
        Else
            'rngP changed
            If bolOChanged(iIndex) Then
                'There was a previous O range change, ignore
                bolOChanged(iIndex) = False 'Delete the recent change flag
                vP(iIndex, 1) = item.Value 'Store the value
            Else
                rngQ(iIndex).Value = item.Value - vP(iIndex, 1)
                MsgBox "Value changed in cell " & item.Address & " from: " & vP(iIndex, 1) & ", to: " & item.Value & ". Difference is: " & item.Value - vP(iIndex, 1)
                vP(iIndex, 1) = item.Value 'Store the value
            End If
        End If
    Next item
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Viktor, I have several questions about the code you attach: Where should I put the code? In a module? In ThisWorkbook? In the worksheet where the operation occurs? All the cells mentioned in the exercise obtain their values ​​through functions similar to this: = 'Sheet10'! L21, that is, they take the existing value in other cells on other sheets, no manual data entry occurs, so I I think (Private Sub Worksheet_Change ...) shouldn't work for me if the change happens through functions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using another code in ThisWorkbook. This code that I am going to attach below allows me to detect changes when cells contain functions, so what should I add?

Comment: '''Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Comment: Put in the sheet object where you have your data. (e.g. double click on sheet1 to open). If you cannot find, google it with pictures.

Comment: Hola @Viktor, I already entered the code correctly in the sheet, it responds very well to the manual changes that I make to each of the cells but I had mentioned that each of the cells of the O2: P20 range contains a function (eg: O2 = 'Sheet5'! M30) therefore: Change event does not detect when a change is made. It is not allowed to make more than one change in O2: P20 and I need it to be allowed.

Comment: The result of the difference of the previous value with the current one is appearing in a window and my intention is to use this result to operate it, could this result be obtained in the range Q2: Q20? I truly apologize for such incitement, my ignorance of VBA has led me to it.@Viktor

Comment: Hello @Viktor, I had not noticed the modification to the code. I have read the code and as I analyze I can understand that no more than one change should occur in the given ranges. These simultaneous changes if they are of my interest. Could the code be modified again to adopt this new condition?

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses more columns of your worksheet to store previous values to be compared to actual values. In my example, the values in cells O2 and O3 will always be the same.
[image: Columns O and P are the source of values. Previous values are stored in columns R and S. The difference is stored in column T]

```
Sub Populate_OandP()

'Store previous values
Call PreviousValues

'This code just simulates the data population in columns O and P
                Dim intRndNumber As Integer

                Range("O2").Value = 10.2
                Range("O3").Value = 10

                intRndNumber = Int((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)

                For i = 4 To 20
                    intRndNumber = Int((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
                    Cells(i, 15).Value = intRndNumber * 10
                Next i

                For i = 2 To 20
                    intRndNumber = Int((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
                    Cells(i, 16).Value = intRndNumber * 10
                Next i

'Check differences
Call CheckDifferenceIfOChanges    

End Sub

Sub PreviousValues()

For i = 2 To 20
    Cells(i, 18).Value = Cells(i, 15).Value
    Cells(i, 19).Value = Cells(i, 16).Value
Next i

End Sub

Sub CheckDifferenceIfOChanges()

For i = 2 To 20
    If Cells(i, 18).Value = Cells(i, 15).Value Then
        Cells(i, 20).Value = Cells(i, 19).Value - Cells(i, 16).Value
    Else: Cells(i, 20).Value = "O columns value changed"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hola @Danilo, After testing the code you attach to me I get the following: When a change is made in any of the cells of the range "O2: O20" it is not maintained, that is: if "O10" = 61, this number is not maintained but changes. The code runs slowly, and it does a somewhat annoying review of each cell. Maybe it is that I put the code wrong? I put it in a module, will it be ok there? As I commented to Viktor, the data entry in each of the cells is through functions, the entry is not manual. Thanks in advance,

Comment: iPerry, please note that I did part of the code just to simulate data in columns O and P. That part of the code should be removed. Everything that is under "'This code just simulates the data population in columns O and P" and above "'Check differences" is there just to simulate data. Try to remove the part I mentioned (not even that I made a different tabulation). In summary, you'll only need "Call PreviousValues" and "Call CheckDifferenceIfOChanges".

Comment: iPerry, in your question you did not mentioned how you wanted to run the code. The solution I presented do not run automatically.